# Re-using HttpClient in Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a consumption-based Azure Function making outgoing HTTP requests when receiving a service bus message. The function is running on the in-process model with a `Startup.cs` file preparing the `HttpClient` for injection:

```cs
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("myclient");
```

Then, in the function, I inject a factory and create a `HttpClient` in the `Run` method:

```cs
public class MyFunction
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory;

    public MyFunction(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        this.httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    [FunctionName("MyFunction")]
    public async Task Run(/* Not really important here */)
    {
        var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("myclient");
        // Use the HttpClient
    }
}
```

I'm starting to see some `SocketException`s when running live. It looks like DNS issues but I was wondering if this could be the connection limit reached in my function app.

It is my understanding that what I'm doing with `IHttpClientFactory` is correct, to avoid the socket exhaustion problem described over and over again. But when reading [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections?tabs=csharp) about connection limits in Azure Functions, it it suggested to create a static `HttpClient`.

Is creating a static shared instance really better than my current approach? And will it potentially fix issues like this? I can be wrong, but using the factory like I've done should be to avoid problems like this and to avoid creating a new instance of the `HttpClient` on every run.

Answer (score 0):

This looks great, you may want to consider validating your approach in the Azure portal.

To do this, simply navigate to your function app blade and click on "Diagnose and Solve problems", followed by "Open Availability and Performance", and then "SNAT Port Exhaustion". Here, you'll be able to review all metrics related to SNAT Port usage and allocation.

For additional information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-intermittent-outbound-connection-errors.